# Reflection about a line as a möbius transformation

Tags: complex-analysis, mobius-transformation

I am trying to find a matrix representation in Mat$_{2×2}(\mathbb C)$ for a reflection about a line $z=z(t) = a+bt$ where only $t$ is restricted to be in $\mathbb R$ as a parameter.

I am thinking that a general reflextion can be viewed as a rotation followed by a reflection about the real line followed by inverse rotation, hence it suffices to find a Möbius representation for the reflection about the real line. However, I am not exactly sure how to find this.

Comment: All mobius transformations are analytic on their domains (i.e., where $cz + d \ne 0$). Reflection in the real line is $z \mapsto \bar{z}$, which is not analytic ($\partial u / \partial x = +1; \partial v / \partial y = -1$). So I don't see how you're going to do this, but maybe I've missed something basic here...could easily happen.

Answer (score 1):

If you try to find a Möbius transformation $T(z)=\frac{az+b}{cz+d}$ that fixes the points on a line, you will get the identity, $T(z)=z$.  This follows from the fact that a Möbius transformation is determined by what it does to $3$ points.  (In fact, a nonidentity Möbius transformation has only two fixed points on the Riemann sphere.)

So reflection in a line can't be expressed as a Möbius transformation.